# In Django, how do I allow print statements to work with Apache WSGI?

Tags: python, django, apache, debugging, wsgi

"print" only works in development server.
But what if I want it to work in Apache? Just in case I forget to comment it out...I want to be able to go smoothly without causing errors.

(Just print to nothing)

Answer (score 9):

As for `quick print`, just can just use:

```
print >>sys.stderr, 'log msg'
```

-- then it lands in error.log, of course.

Comment: Another way to quick print to stderr is `sys.stderr.write('log mgs')`

Answer (score 6):

See Graham Dumpleton's post:

- [WSGI and printing to standard output](http://blog.dscpl.com.au/2009/04/wsgi-and-printing-to-standard-output.html)

Comment: In particular note that if using mod_wsgi 3.X or later then this isn't an issue at all, as default was changed to allow sys.stdout to be used because too many people were plain lazy to fix up code. Just hope you never need to use any of the CGI/WSGI adapters out there at the moment because things will screw up if print to sys.stdout with them.

Answer (score 3):

What you're proposing is a Bad Idea, but if you insist on doing it anyways, check out the [mod_wsgi configuration directives](http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/ConfigurationDirectives):

**WSGIRestrictStdout**

```
Description: Enable restrictions on use of STDOUT.
Syntax:      WSGIRestrictStdout On|Off
Default:     WSGIRestrictStdout On
Context:     server config
Module:      mod_wsgi.c
```

> A well behaved Python WSGI application
>   should never attempt to write any data
>   directly to sys.stdout or use the
>   print statement without directing it
>   to an alternate file object. This is
>   because ways of hosting WSGI
>   applications such as CGI use standard
>   output as the mechanism for sending
>   the content of a response back to the
>   web server. If a WSGI application were
>   to directly write to sys.stdout it
>   could interfere with the operation of
>   the WSGI adapter and result in
>   corruption of the output stream.
>
> In the interests of promoting
>   portability of WSGI applications,
>   mod_wsgi restricts access to
>   sys.stdout and will raise an exception
>   if an attempt is made to use
>   sys.stdout explicitly.
>
> The only time that one might want to
>   remove this restriction is purely out
>   of convencience of being able to use
>   the print statement during debugging
>   of an application, or if some third
>   party module or WSGI application was
>   errornously using print when it
>   shouldn't. If restrictions on using
>   sys.stdout are removed, any data
>   written to it will instead be sent
>   through to sys.stderr and will appear
>   in the Apache error log file.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to write print statements to Apache error log, you can use `sys.stderr`:

```
import sys
sys.stderr.write('log mgs')
```

then it will be in apache error log file.