# django print information on production server

Tags: django, apache, debugging, mod-wsgi

I have some prints on my application for debug purpose. On the production server where these printed information goes? on apache log? I am using apache/mod_wsgi .

Thanks.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

use logging

I like to log to file at times so I use the following in my settings.py

```
import logging


logging.basicConfig(
    level = logging.INFO,
    format = '%(asctime)s %(levelname)s %(message)s',
    filename = '/tmp/djangoLog.log',)
```

and where I want logging:

```
import logging

logging.info("Making the alpha-ldap connection")
```

then in /tmp/djangoLog.log I would see the line "Making the alpha-ldap connection"e

Answer (score 2):

Check this thread for some pointers: [In Django, how do I allow print statements to work with Apache WSGI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3543572/in-django-how-do-i-allow-print-statements-to-work-with-apache-wsgi)

That said, you shouldn't use print statements for debugging on your production system, especially as django comes with a nice, flexible [logging module](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/logging/) included nowadays.

Comment: I forget what component it is but I know when I upgraded to Django 1.3 I had to remove all print statements.