# Django not writing errors to log files in production

Tags: django, nginx, fastcgi, production-environment

So i am trying do deply my django app + nginx (fastcgi). I am trying to write all my normal django output (that i usually get when developing the app) but in production since i dont see the output, i am trying to write it to a log file with this command :

> sudo python manage.py runfcgi host=localhost port=8000 >
>   /var/log/djangolog.log

But for some reason nothing is being written. But the thing is my other apps (like celery and redis) are able to write to my log files.

How can i fix this?

UPDATE:

thanks to this https://stackoverflow.com/a/5653633/977622 i am now able to print my debug info, but i want the info about requests that are made and so on.. how do i achieve that?

info i want is like this:

```
[23/May/2013 20:49:59] "GET /static/js/bootstrap-carousel.js HTTP/1.1" 200 5018
[23/May/2013 20:49:59] "GET /static/js/bootstrap-typeahead.js HTTP/1.1" 200 7074
[23/May/2013 20:49:59] "GET /static/js/bootstrap-datepicker.js HTTP/1.1" 200 11684
[23/May/2013 20:49:59] "GET /static/js/bootstrap-colorpicker.js HTTP/1.1" 200 18009
[23/May/2013 20:49:59] "GET /static/img/icon_16.png HTTP/1.1" 200 623
[23/May/2013 20:49:59] "GET /static/img/smartblack.png HTTP/1.1" 200 25805
[23/May/2013 20:50:06] "GET /accounts/logout/ HTTP/1.1" 200 2308
[23/May/2013 20:50:07] "GET /accounts/login/ HTTP/1.1" 200 2701
[23/May/2013 20:50:07] "GET /static/img/auth-icons.png HTTP/1.1" 200 7306
[23/May/2013 20:50:15] "POST /accounts/login/ HTTP/1.1" 200 2770
```

my settings.py:

```
LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    'handlers': {
        'mail_admins': {
            'level': 'ERROR',
            'class': 'django.utils.log.AdminEmailHandler'
        }
    },
    'loggers': {
        'django.request': {
            'handlers': ['mail_admins'],
            'level': 'ERROR',
            'propagate': True,
        },
    }
}
import logging

logging.basicConfig(
    level = logging.INFO,
    format = '%(asctime)s %(levelname)s %(message)s',
    filename = '/var/log/djangoLog.log',)
```

Comment: what value have `LOGGING` in settings.py?

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/logging/

Comment: i updated my question with my current logging, but i am not using it in my code (i think) because i want to see the errors, not "print"

Comment: What do you mean by "in production"? Do you mean you've set the `DEBUG` setting to `False`? If so, then yes, all error output is not shown by design. Write your won Django log handler if as already proposed in the comments. If that's not what you mean here, please elaborate more on why you think you're not using the Django logging framework.

Comment: my DEBUG is set to TRUE.. so i dont understand.. anyways when i run my server in my testing environment (my computer) i am able so see all kinds of errors. no that its in the server, and DEBUT is set to true, the output is not being written to my log file so i can see every request that are made and the errors and so on.. do you understand now?

Comment: thanks to this http://stackoverflow.com/a/5653633/977622 i am now able to print my debug info, but i want the info about requests that are made and so on.. how do i achieve that?