# How to get all prints on django production server with apache

Tags: django, logging, printing, production

Please tell me how can I get all prints that I see when I run ./manage.py runserver locally. I dont want to use logger. Ideally I would like to connect to my manage.py and see what is server is printing for me now.
I tried [django print information on production server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5653566/django-print-information-on-production-server) with no success.
I know that i cat just tail -f logfile and i will see last lines, but i could not find where is my prints located. Please help.
Here is my logging config:

```
LOGGING = {
'version': 1,
'disable_existing_loggers': False,
'filters': {
    'require_debug_false': {
        '()': 'django.utils.log.RequireDebugFalse'
    },
    'require_debug_true': {
        '()': 'django.utils.log.RequireDebugTrue'
    }
},
'formatters': {
    'main_formatter': {
        'format': '%(levelname)s:%(name)s: %(message)s '
                 '(%(asctime)s; %(filename)s:%(lineno)d)',
        'datefmt': "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S",
    },
},
'handlers': {
    'mail_admins': {
        'level': 'ERROR',
        'filters': ['require_debug_false'],
        'class': 'django.utils.log.AdminEmailHandler'
    },
    'console':{
        #'level': 'DEBUG',
        'level': 'ERROR',
        'filters': ['require_debug_true'],
        'class': 'logging.StreamHandler',
        'formatter': 'main_formatter',
    },
    'production_file':{
        'level' : 'INFO',
        'class' : 'logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler',
        'filename' : 'logs/main.log',
        'maxBytes': 1024*1024*5, # 5 MB
        'backupCount' : 7,
        'formatter': 'main_formatter',
        'filters': ['require_debug_false'],
    },
    'debug_file':{
        'level' : 'DEBUG',
        'class' : 'logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler',
        'filename' : 'logs/main_debug.log',
        'maxBytes': 1024*1024*5, # 5 MB
        'backupCount' : 7,
        'formatter': 'main_formatter',
        'filters': ['require_debug_true'],
    },
    'null': {
        "class": 'django.utils.log.NullHandler',
    }
},
'loggers': {
    'django.request': {
        'handlers': ['mail_admins', 'console'],
        'level': 'ERROR',
        'propagate': True,
    },
    'django': {
        'handlers': ['null', ],
    },
    'py.warnings': {
        'handlers': ['null', ],
    },
    '': {
        'handlers': ['console', 'production_file', 'debug_file'],
        'level': "DEBUG",
    },
}
```

}

Comment: Why you don't want do use logging? Is simplest solution and will allow you to do exactly what you need.

Answer (score 3):

If you run your application in production setup, i.e. APACHE server your can find prints in file located in destination, which you configured in your apache config.
For example: 'ErrorLog /var/log/httpd-error.log'

Comment: Thank you! That really helps.

Comment: All other guys just make down-vote, but you give me solution i need.

Comment: @DmitryYudin if you provided a little context and rationale in the question you might get more constructive responses from the "other guys". ;)

Answer (score 1):

Django can be run as multi-threaded server without master, so there is no simple way to join all std output together. Logging is simplest and best solution here, you can define many log handlers, even send all logs into some socket, where some simple logging server will reside that will catch all logs and print them into console. Running that server on screen will allow you to connect to it and see some last messages from it.