# Not able to resolve MultiValueDictKeyError at ['document']

Tags: python, django

I want to upload an excel file to the server but I'm getting an error as MultiValueDictKeyError at ['document'] in the below mentioned code.

***views.py***

```
def index(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        uploaded_file = request.FILES['document']
        print(uploaded_file.name)
        print(uploaded_file.size)
    return render(request, "polls/upload.html")
```

***upload.html***

```
<form  method="POST"  enctype="multipart/form-data">
{% csrf_token %}
{{ form.as_p }}
<input type="file" name="document">
<button type="submit">Upload</button>
</form>
```

I want to be able to upload the file but I'm getting an error as MultiValueDictKeyError at ['document']. Can anyone please tell me what is wrong with the code?

Comment: Your code says "document" but your error message says "documents". Have you pasted a different version of your code by any chance?

Comment: @KentShikama Sorry, it was supposed to be ['document'] in the question too.

Comment: @KentShikama Do you know why the error is being raised? :/

Comment: I don't see any issues as of now but feel free to post the results of `print(request.FILES)` right before you call `request.FILES['document']`.

Comment: @newbie you should be using `get` method of the `request.FILES` - `request.FILES.get('documents', None)`, I think this would work.

Comment: @KentShikama This didn't work. Getting back the same error.

Comment: @GiorgiJambazishvili This doesn't work as well. Says "MultiValueDict has no attribute GET" :/

Comment: @newbie I wasn't expecting it to work; I was hoping you would show us the output of that print statement.

Comment: @KentShikama def index(request):
 if request.method == 'POST':
  print(request.FILES)
  uploaded_file = request.FILES['document']
  print(uploaded_file.name)
  print(uploaded_file.size)
 return render(request, "polls/upload.html")
You mean like this? If yes, I don't see anything else except the error. Also, why are we using print statement before even calling request.FILES['document']? Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Yeah. Are you running this on a dev server or on something like wsgi; if the later, print statements won't show up. See https://stackoverflow.com/q/3543572/2750819 . Also can you show us more of your stacktrace?

Comment: @KentShikama I'm using Django development server. The stack trace: Request Method: POST
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/polls/
Django Version: 2.2.7
Exception Type: MultiValueDictKeyError
Exception Value: 
'document'

Comment: The print statement should show up in your stdout then.